# How to refresh the viewcontrollers in inside Scrollview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

I have Set of view controllers in inside of scrollview it connected with scrollview menus.when i click the menu from menu scroll it show the respected viewcontrollers. but all the view controllers loaded initially. I need to reload the view controllers when i click the respected menu. My code look like

```
btnArray = @[@"Dashboard", @"Daily Log", @"Labour Timesheet", @"Work Safety", @"Soil", @"Equipment", @"Site Photos", @"Quick Links", @"Printable Forms"];
[self addButtonsInScrollMenu:btnArray];


DashBoardViewController *dashboardVC = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Dashboard"];
DailyReportListViewController *dailyLogVC = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DailyReportListVC"];
TimeSheetListViewController *labourTimesheetVC = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TimeSheetListVC"];
SafetyReportListViewController *workSafetyVC = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SafetyReportListVC"];
DashBoardViewController *soilVC = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Dashboard"];
DashBoardViewController *equipmentVC = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Dashboard"];
DashBoardViewController *sitePhotosVC = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Dashboard"];
DashBoardViewController *quickLinksVC = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Dashboard"];
DashBoardViewController *printableFormsVC = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Dashboard"];

controllerArray = @[dashboardVC, dailyLogVC, labourTimesheetVC, workSafetyVC, soilVC, equipmentVC, sitePhotosVC, quickLinksVC, printableFormsVC];
[self addChildViewControllersOntoContainer:controllerArray];
```

Comment: Provide screen shot of your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through controllerArray and call **viewDidLoad**